# Launch a process in ASP?

Tags: asp-classic, process

I am working on an old ASP web app (not .net) and I need to launch a separate process (exe). After much googling I have yet to find a valid way of doing this. Anyone have any suggestions?

Does CreateProcess work in ASP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to have full control of the server, as this is considered **very** insecure.  It's unlikely a hosting service will allow you to do this.

```
<script language="VBScript"> 
    Sub Scan 
        Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

        'objShell.Run "C:\MyApp.exe"
        objshell.Exec "C:\MyApp.exe" 

    End Sub
</script>
```

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/david.wang/archive/2006/04/28/HOWTO-Run-Console-Applications-from-IIS6-on-Windows-Server-2003-Part-2.aspx) is an article that explains the whole process.

Comment: Thanks! This sort of works! I can run commands like "cmd /c dir" which work fine, but when I try a path to an exe I keep getting an error saying the file cannot be found. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Nevermind. I got it. Web server was using a networked resource so I was putting the exe file in the wrong location. Not to mention the QA servers are load balanced which I only found out later. Thanks!